# Prove that $\int_0^1\frac{\sin(\log(x))}{\sqrt x}dx$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I need to prove that:

$$\int_0^1\frac{\sin(\log(x))}{\sqrt x}\ dx$$

converges. I can't figure out how to start the proof since the function takes positive and negative values the majorant princinciple can't be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: Does it converge absolutely?

Comment: Aaaah, that solves it!

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin\log x}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx = \text{Im}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{i\log x}}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx =\text{Im}\int_{0}^{1}x^{i-1/2}\,dx= \text{Im}\left(\frac{1}{i+\tfrac{1}{2}}\right)=\color{red}{-\frac{4}{5}}. $$